# send key pressed on Datagridview to a textbox without focusing textbox in .net winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with more than 200 rows and ReadOnly property True. When your type any character over the datagirdview then, that character must be sent to the Textbox within same form.

Dgg is datagridview and textbox1 Textbox in which this keypress must be sent. I tried code below but it is not sending keys to the Textbox1

```
  Private Sub DGG_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DGG.KeyPress
        SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar) '' How to send this Key to Textbox1 ''
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just try putting a focus before you send the keychar to textbox. ie

```
Private Sub DGG_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DGG.KeyPress
        Textbox1.Focus()
        SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar) 
    End Sub
```

hope it helps.

Comment: i dont want to focus the textbox as i mentioned in question, is there any way to do that ?